# For all $n$, $9^n + 25^n - 1$ has a prime factor with $7$ in its decimal representation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, conjectures

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of positive integers defined by $x_n=9^n + 25^n -1$ for all $n \ge 2$

I conjectured that there exists at least one prime divisor of $x_n$ which contains $7 $ in its decimal representation for each $n$

Can anyone prove/disprove this?

Comment: Fine. So what is your question?

Comment: Prove or disprove this conjecture...

Comment: What's your motivation in saying this? Doesn't every positive integer greater than $1$ have a prime divisor?

Comment: Maybe they mean the *prime divisor* has $7$ in its base 10 expansion?

Comment: Casteels correctly got my point...

Comment: I edited the post to make your intended question more clear. (By the way, the word for base-10 representation is *decimal*, not *digital*). So what's the motivation then in thinking that there's a prime factor has $7$ in it? I'm interested to know

Comment: Not every.... At least one prime divisor has 7 in its decimal representation.

Comment: I was just experimenting with numbers while i observed this result...

Comment: what is the conjecture?

Comment: For each n the number x(n) has atleast one prime factor containing 7 in its decimal representation.

Comment: It's probably very difficult if it's true.

Comment: Hmm i know.. Thats why i posted my conjecture here...

Comment: To be completely honest, it'll probably be extremely difficult to prove, and it's not really that interesting. Past the first $10$ or so $n$, the numbers get so unwieldingly large that there *probably* is a $7$ somewhere there in its decimal representation. The only easy way that we would come to any conclusion is if we were able to say it is divisible by $7$ for all $n$, which is not the case.

Comment: The conjecture is mercilessly true for $n \leq 41$.

Comment: @user92774 ! It is difficult to prove/disprove thats why it is not interesting?

Comment: 010001001# what happens after n≥41??

Comment: A bit heuristic: Divisibility by a given prime $p$ is periodic in $n$, which means that "there are not enough small primes" to completely factor $x(n)$ except for the first few $n$. So after that we expect big primes to occur as factors and big primes have so many digits that the lack of a $7$  in their digits is rare.

Comment: @01000100 ... also up to including $x(52)= 3\cdot 144071\cdot 340057\cdot 2431414200115510028078911\cdot 344914908325541270069688230259106727003$. Again, since the total number of digits in all prime factors is essentially the number of digits in $x(n)$ itself, it is more than likely that a 7 occurs.

Comment: But that isnt a concrete proof/disproof of my conjecture! #Hagen von Eitzen

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Great heuristic justification I must say

Comment: Souvik try it bro...

Comment: With the help of an online database, I checked upto n=100 and the conjecture remains true. There is very little hope to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* amenable to a heuristic argument.  The prime factors are not normal for base ten.  In particular, digits $\{0, 3, 5, 6, 8\}$ are avoided while $\{1, 4, 7, 9\}$ contend for most frequent (weighting by length).  $8$ first occurs as a digit of $3274891$ for $n = 5$ but not in any factor for $n = \{9, 10, 11, 16, 21\}$.  $0$ first occurs for $n = 8$, and then only because $152630937345$ happens to be fifteen times a prime number.  Probably $9^n$ and $25^n$ are producing a subtle interference phenomenon in the *p*-adics.

For $n = 20$, $9$ is not a digit of a prime factor (the GPF has 18 digits) and $7$ *occurs only as the units digit* of three factors (out of six).  This pattern repeats at $n = 24$, substituting $3$ for $7$ (the GPF has 22 digits and somehow excludes $\{3, 6, 9\}$ but not $0$, despite that $9^{24} + 25^{24} - 1 = 3552713678880267372432493847753985$ contains one $0$ and twice the expected number of $3$s).

Comment: An observation: if $p = 2k + 1$ is a prime factor, it occurs with a period of $k$ units of $n$.  $7$ is _never_ a prime factor.

$$
\begin{alignat}{3}
3 & \mid \{33, 705, 16353, \dots\} \\
5 & \mid \{705, 397185, \dots\};\ && n = \{2, 4, 6, \dots\} \\
11 & \mid \{33, 244672065, \dots\};\ && n = \{1, 6, 11, \dots\} \\
23 & \mid \{16353, \dots\};\ && n = \{3, 14, 25, \dots\} \\
47 & \mid \{705, 363797882060023012839007713, \dots\};\ && n = \{2, \textbf{19}, 25, \textbf{42}, \dots\} \\
\end{alignat}
$$

Comment: A more interesting question might be ___what happened to all the other primes containing 7?___  Of the nine primes less than $100$ containing a $7$, four begin with $\{0, 3, 6, 9\}$.  These do not divide any terms in the sequence.  $17$ and $73$ are also excluded (empirically). $\{47, 71, 79\}$ remain, with oscillatory gaps between them — and apparently some huge prime containing $7$ always completes a period at exactly the right time for _every_ gap to be filled.